# Outline goes white in color during transition in Firefox only

Tags: html, css

Can't get my head around this one. I have a button that can be pushed, and I'm using an outline to highlight the selection. This works perfectly on every browser except for Firefox; the outline goes white in color for the duration of the transition.

```
.pricing-experience .flex_column {
   color: #fff;
   min-height: 420px;
   font-size: 11px;
   padding: 35px;
   width: 31%;
   margin-left: 3.5%;
   -webkit-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
   -o-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
   -moz-transition: all 50ms ease-in;
   transition: all 50ms ease-in;
}

.bgOutline {
    background: rgba(57, 60, 67, 0.72);
    outline: 2px solid #FF6969 !important;
}
```

Thanks so much for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to add a default transparent outline to non-hover or click outline first to prevent unexpected glitch from browsers

```
.pricing-experience .flex_column {
    outline: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: You know, I spent a solid hour trying to figure that out, and I don't know why I didn't think to try this. Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!